# Can not Read Bitmap data of a (1280 x 960) .bmp image In C

Tags: c, bitmap, bitmapdata

I'm trying to open a .bmp image file and to read bitmap data to a buffer. but I'm not getting the excepted output. I'm new to C language and please assist me on this case.

this is my "main.c" file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t DWORD;   // DWORD = unsigned 32 bit value
typedef uint16_t WORD;    // WORD = unsigned 16 bit value

#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct {
    WORD bfType;  //specifies the file type
    DWORD bfSize;  //specifies the size in bytes of the bitmap file
    WORD bfReserved1;  //reserved; must be 0
    WORD bfReserved2;  //reserved; must be 0
    DWORD offset;  //specifies the offset in bytes from the bitmapfileheader to the bitmap bits
} BMP_FILE_HEADER;

#pragma pack(pop)

 unsigned char *LoadBitmapFile(char *filename)
{
    FILE *filePtr;  //our file pointer
    BMP_FILE_HEADER bitmapFileHeader;  //our bitmap file header
    unsigned char *bitmapImage;  //store image data
    size_t bytes_read;

    //open file in read binary mode
    filePtr = fopen(filename,"rb");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    //read the bitmap file header
    fread(&bitmapFileHeader,1,sizeof(BMP_FILE_HEADER),filePtr);
    printf("Type : %d \n",bitmapFileHeader.bfType );

    //verify that this is a .BMP file by checking bitmap id
    if (bitmapFileHeader.bfType !=0x4D42)
    {
        printf("This is not a bitmap" );

        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    //move file pointer to the beginning of bitmap data
    fseek(filePtr,bitmapFileHeader.offset, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Where is the file pointer = %ld \n", ftell(filePtr) );

    //allocate enough memory for the bitmap image data
    bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(1280*960);

    //verify memory allocation
    if (!bitmapImage)
    {   
      printf("Memory Allocation failed" );
        free(bitmapImage);
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }


    //read in the bitmap image data
    bytes_read = fread(bitmapImage,1,1280*960 ,filePtr);
    printf("Read Bytes : %zu\n",bytes_read );

    //make sure bitmap image data was read
    if (bitmapImage == NULL)
    {
      printf("data was not read" );
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("bitmapImage: %s\n", bitmapImage );

    printf("Header- size -> %i\n",bitmapFileHeader.bfSize );
    printf("Header- OffSet -> %i\n",bitmapFileHeader.offset );

    //close file and return bitmap image data
    fclose(filePtr);
    return bitmapImage;
}

int  main(){
  
  unsigned char *bitmapData;
  bitmapData = LoadBitmapFile("img_06.bmp");
  
  printf("bitmapData: %s", bitmapData );

return 0;
}
```

This is the output :

[image: Output Of the program]

I can not print any data of the "bitmapData" buffer. This is the .bmp file which I used in the program.

> Image size
> (1,229,878 bytes)
> width 1280 pixels /
> height 960 pixels

[image: img_06.bmp]

Comment: `%s` stops printing when it sees `0x00`. Try `printf("bitmapData: %d", bitmapData[0] );` to print the first byte.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you very much. I tried to print using a for loop.  It prints integer values.  Is there a way to print char s?  something like -> printf("bitmapData: %c", bitmapData[0] )

Comment: `printf("bitmapData: "); fwrite(bitmapData, 1280*960, 1, stdout);`?

Comment: In general, this is binary image data, not a string. Trying to print the data as a string is a nonsensical operation... as is trying to print each char with `"%c"`. There are several non-printable characters. Looking at the integer values (in your base of choice) for each byte is really the only way to "see" the raw data.

Comment: Your check `if (bitmapImage == NULL)` after `fread` is also nonsense/useless, you need to check the return value `bytes_read` to determine what happened with the read. The only place you need to check `bitmapImage` for validity is after the call to `malloc`, as you do.

Comment: Also, why not `malloc(bfSize)` (or would it be `bfSize - sizeof(BMP_FILE_HEADER)`?). There should be a way to determine/derive the amount of data you need to `malloc` rather than using a hardcoded constant. In a naive/easy approach, you could at least `malloc` the file size, making your code work with any bitmap file instead of only those that match 1280x960.

Comment: @yano Thank you very much for you comments. really helpful. actually I need to create a.raw file after removing the header part  of a .bmp image. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Yeah, read in just the image data, then you can `fwrite` it to disk. I don't know .bmp file format off the top, but presumably the actual picture data comes after the header at some constant/derivable offset, you'll need to figure that out.

Comment: @yano I did write the returned bitmapData to a file. but it is having only 8 bytes. what is the reason and how can I solve it? please help

Comment: Could be anything, would need to see some code. Should be as simple as `fwrite(myImageDataPtr, 1, amountOfImageData, myOutputFile);` You need to make sure `myOutputFile` is opened for binary writing. There are plenty of `fwrite` tutorials online. If you've been through those and you're still stuck you're better off asking a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I replaced the line,
printf("bitmapData: %s", bitmapData );

with 
printf("bitmapData: "); fwrite(bitmapData, 1280*960, 1, stdout);
```